# linked page didn't update in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm implementing an Android app for guitar chord recognition. My first layout xml is fine and it's updated, but when I click on login button it goes to next page and didn't show anything on it.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:background="@drawable/background"
   tools:context="com.example.guitarchordrecognition.MainActivity" >

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/user"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/user" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/user"
    android:layout_below="@+id/user"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/pass"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/user"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:text="@string/login"
     />

</lativeLayout>
```

afterlogin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/background" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
    android:text="Button 1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button 2" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button mybutton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mybutton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.login);
    mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        private void buttonclick()
        {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.guitarchordrecognition.Afterlogin"));
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch(v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.login:
                buttonclick();
                break;
            }


        }
    });

}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.guitarchordrecognition"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Afterlogin"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.guitarchordrecognition.Afterlogin" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you use `action` constructor, but this time
try `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Afterlogin.class));` instead.